# Push to viewcontroller and parse data

Tags: objective-c

I have a simple UITableView which is suppose to push to a new Viewcontroller. When the Cell is pressed it should push to the new viewcontroller and send what number of row has been pushed. Is there a way to obtain this?

This is what i have at the moment, which dosent do anything.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    YoutubeViewController *youtubeViewController = [[YoutubeViewController alloc]        initWithNibName:@"YoutubeViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:youtubeViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You must push your view controller in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. To send selected row to view controller,just declare a row property in view controller, and set in after view controller initialization.

Comment: can you paste some code whatever you done in didselectmethod and name of viewcontrollor which you want to push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

This method is the delegate that will be called when a the user selects a cell in tableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     //Write code here to push your viewcontroller
     YourViewController *controller=[[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     controller.selectedRowValue = indexPath.row;
     [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

**In YourViewController.h**

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController

@property int selectedRowValue;

@end
```

**In YourViewController.m**

```
@implementation YourViewController
@synthesize selectedRowValue;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Selected Row %d",selectedRowValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check protocol of UITableViewController delegate https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html.
Method You are looking for

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

yes do one thing

create property of integer type in your `YoutubeViewController`

like this

```
@property int selectedRowValue;
```

after that syntsize it in YoutubeViewController.m class

```
  // YoutubeViewController.m
  @implementation YoutubeViewController
  @synthesize selectedRowValue
```

now you come class where ur table is and make some changes to it as shown bellow

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  YoutubeViewController *youtubeViewController = [[YoutubeViewController alloc]        initWithNibName:@"YoutubeViewController" bundle:nil];
   youtubeViewController.selectedRowValue=indexPath.row;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:youtubeViewController animated:YES];
}
```

now every thing done to check index value selected in youtube class `NSLogout` the value

```
 //YoutubeViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {

  // nslogout the value to check
   NSLog(@"yours data selected from table%d",selectedRowValue);
  }
```

now every thing done .
enjoy coding

Even you dont want this you can go by creating `Constructor` or by storing the value to  `NSUserDefaults`